# Bundler: using shared gem when it exists, rather than downloading from gem server

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

Say, I have Gemfile like following.

```
source "GEM_REPOSITORY"

gem 'gem_A'
# gem_A has no additional dependency

gem 'gem_B'
# gem_B depends on gem_B_1 and gem_B_2
```

When I run `bundle install`, I want Bundler to do the following.

1. If a gem already exists in "local system-wide gems", it copies the gem from local.
2. If a gem doesn't exist in local, it looks for GEM_REPOSITORY.

I looked for some related articles, and found some of likely-answers like

- [Ruby Bundler multiple sources in Gemfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072412/ruby-bundler-multiple-sources-in-gemfile)
- [SOURCE PRIORITY](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/gemfile.5.html#SOURCE-PRIORITY)

But none of the above looks like the answer for me.
Using source repository priority does't work. Because in the example above, if dependent gem (say, `gem_B_1`) exits in local but the target gem (`gem_B`) doesn't exist in local, it'll download both of above from the remote repository.

Are there any work around for doing this?
If not, don't you guys think it's necessary considering the cost of the implementation and the effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the current behavior.
When running `gem install`, directly or via `bundle install`, `gem` will first build a dependency graph with all the needed gems. If the `gem` is found locally it will use it, otherwise it will try to download it from the specified source.

If you want, try it yourself.

```
bundle gem gem_a
bundle gem gem_b
cd gem_a
vim gem_a.gemspec
```

add

```
spec.add_dependency 'multi_json', '~> 1.10.1'
```

or any dependency you want to the gem and run bundle install.

```
cd ../gem_b
vim Gemfile
```

and add

```
gem 'gem_a', path: '../gem_a'
```

then run

```
bundle install --verbose
```

you will see that the `multi_json` or whatever dependency of `gem_a` uses the local version and does not download anything.

This is of course also true for gems from remote sources.

Comment: Looks like it was my misunderstanding. Thanks!