# How can I avoid bundlers warning about multiple sources when I have all gems in my .gemspec?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemspecs

In my own gem, I have a `Gemfile` that looks basically like this:

```
source 'https://my.gemserver.com'
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gemspec
```

My `.gemspec` has all dependencies listed as `add_dependency` and `add_development_dependency`.

As of Bundler 1.8, I get the warning:

```
Warning: this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources. Using `source` more than
once without a block is a security risk, and may result in installing unexpected gems.
To resolve this warning, use a block to indicate which gems should come from the
secondary source. To upgrade this warning to an error,
run `bundle config disable_multisource true`.
```

Is there a way to resolve this warning (without muting via bundle config)? I cannot find anything about a source option in the Rubygems specification.

Comment: Have you tried using a source block like this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25300592)?

Comment: The thing is, I don't list my gem dependencies in the Gemfile. They are all listed in the .gemspec. Do I have to duplicate them in the Gemfile? Then what's the point of referring to the gemspec?

Comment: @ChristophPetschnig [Here](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/) is a nice article on roles that `Gemfile` and `.gemspec` hold.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thank you. Still, it talks about avoiding duplication. Using the source block (which makes a lot of sense) means duplication. Also, I am getting more and more doubts on `add_development_dependency` in the .gemspec. I believe this comes from a pre-bundler era and gems there should belong to the Gemfile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you'll either need to mute the warning or add the source block to your `Gemfile` with the specific gems you want to come from your private server. There isn't a need to duplicate the ones that come from `rubygems.org` (or you could do it the other way around, if you depend on more private gems than public ones, and your private gems do not themselves depend on public ones).

The problem is that the `gemspec` format has no support for specifying the source for each gem, so without duplicating them into the `Gemfile`, there is no way to specify which gems come from each source.

Comment: Which is a bug that should be addressed! (imho)

Comment: FYI, further discussion about the reason for this is in this issue: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3576

Answer (score 6):

Kind of sad, but one has to move it out to Gemfile :-(

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://my.gemserver.com' do
  your_gem1
  your_gem2
  #...
end

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gemspec
```

but then, if some of your gems should be included in `:development` or `:test` group, following could be used

Gemfile:

```
your_gem1, :source => 'https://my.gemserver.com'
#...
group :development do
  your_gem2, :source => 'https://my.gemserver.com'
  #...
end

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gemspec
```

Comment: But what about gem compilation? This gems will be included in the release?

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on the discussion on [the `bundler` issue](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3576), as previous answers have stated, you *must* include the gem in you `Gemfile`. However, you only need to specify the version of the gem in your `.gemspec`. If you change versions more often than private dependencies this isn't a terrible solution.

Reference the gem without version in `Gemfile`:

```
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

source 'https://xxx@gem.fury.io/me/' do
  gem 'my-private-dependency'
end

gemspec
```

Reference the gem with version specification in the `.gemspec`:

```
# my-gem.gemspec
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.add_dependency 'my-private-dependency', '~> 0.1.5'
end
```